# Hiding and Showing Bootstrap Grid Columns

Tags: css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to adapt bootstrap's standard practices to speed up some of my development but have a quick question related to showing and hiding cols.

I have the following simple layout

```
<div class="row" id="contactGrid">

<div class="col-sm-2">Sidebar</div>
<div class="col-sm-10">Content</div>

</div>
```

When I use AngularJS to show/hide the Sidebar col I expect the Content col to stretch the entire  width of the container but it doesn't it says at 'col-10'.  Do I need to programmically change the class/width to col-sm-12 when I hide the sidebar?

Thanks for your help, I'm sure this is an easy one!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The element with the class `col-sm-10` will always have 10/12 of the width of it's parent row. Therefore you need to update it on the fly, when your sidebar changes to hidden. As you already use AngularJS you might have a variable defining if your sidebar should be visible or not. This variable may also define your class conditionally for your content div.

```
<div class="row" id="contactGrid">
  <div class="col-sm-2" ng-show="booleanVariable">Sidebar</div>
  <div ng-class="{col-sm-10: booleanVariable, col-sm-12: !booleanVariable}">Content</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Daniel,

Your answer is the reason I'm trying to learn the BS/NG style of UI.  It's just knowling where the shortcuts begin and end.  To polish it off I used a ternary expression in the ng-class.  showFilterSidebar is my hide/show variable.  Thanks Again!

```
<div ng-class="showFilterSidebar ? 'col-sm-10' : 'col-sm-12'">
```

Comment: I agree with you, this solution is even better readable as mine. Have fun with angular ;)

Answer (score 0):

Yes you need to change class to `col-sm-12` and hide for `col-sm-2` to avoid problems with floatin .